# Flutter - How to move and zoom Canvas drawings without AGAIN running something like the CustomPainter paint method?

Tags: flutter, canvas, transform, scale, custom-painting

I have tried using the methods "Transform.scale" (for "zooming" ) and "Transform.translate" (for the moving), but they seem to trigger the paint method in the CustomPainter.
(even though the method "shouldRepaint" returns false, but that method is not even invoked)
Maybe there is some other way of doing what I want i.e. be able to move and zoom something I have created with a Canvas (without again executing the paint method)?

In the below example code there are three sliders, one for zooming out (i.e. reducing the size) and one for moving horizontally and one for moving vertically.
The "paint" method simply draws a polygon (see the below attached screenshot picture).

While the example code below is simple (i.e. small amount of hardcoded vector data and fast to render), I want to emphasize that the solution I am looking for need to support MANY complicated drawings (with LOTS OF data, slow to render), i.e. it is not an acceptable solution to suggest something like instead manually converting this one vector image to a raster image (e.g. PNG/JPG/GIF).

Below I try do describe how you can think regarding a scenario that need to be supported:
Imagine you want to implement an app with a huge dropdown list with lots of different vector data images to be selected.
The data of those VECTOR images may be retrieved from the internet or from a big local SQLite database.
IMPORTANT: The DATA in those images are NOT raster images such as jpg, png, gif... but the VECTOR data to become retrieved is defined as lots of screen coordinates for points, lines, polygons, and textual labels, and icons, and color values... and so on.
Such VECTOR data will then be used for creating the image, and as far as I understand you should use CustomPainter with the paint method unless there are better options?
Also imagine that each of such selected image with vector data is HUGE with MANY THOUSANDS of lines, polygons, icons, ... and so on, and that the paint method might take seconds for creating the image.
BUT, once it is drawn the data will not change.
So, since the "paint" method might take seconds to render a huge amount of vector data, you want to avoid invoking it frequently, when moving or zooming.
Therefore I think it would be desirable if it would be possible to use the method "shouldRepaint" to return false, but it seems as that method is not even invoked at all when resizing or moving with the  Transform methods "scale" and "translate".
But maybe there is some other solution to support the above described scenario, maybe some other class than CustomPainter that do not automatically trigger the paint method when applying Transform scale/translate ?
I hope there is a solution with the Flutter framework somehow being able to automatically reuse the bitmap (e.g color values at certain bits and bytes) that was created potentially slowly with a paint method but can scale/zoom and move it in a faster way than having to execute the paint method again.  [image]

Comment: tried `RepaintBoundary`? for example with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406157/2252830) you can create multiple "layers" if you want any of them to change

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I tried to use it with the example code I provided in the question above.
In the constructor I modified it to let the Container be surrounded by an RepaintBoundary (and updated the datatype of the instance variable from Container to InteractiveViewer) i.e. I replaced "... = Container ..." with "... = RepaintBoundary(child: Container ...)".
But since you added a comment rather than an answer it seems as I can not click to "Accept your answer" as the solution.

Comment: @user743436 I want to do similar thing, can you share the code snippet ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? @user743436

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to zoom, scale, pan on your images, then you can try the new InteractiveViewer widget.

> **[InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) class**
>
> A widget that enables pan and zoom
> interactions with its child.
>
> The user can transform the child by dragging to pan or pinching to
> zoom.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

Comment: Sorry but no I do not think it helps to use the InteractiveViewer.
I tried to use it with the example code I provided in the question above.
In the constructor I modified it to let the Container be surrounded by an InteractiveViewer (and updated the datatype of the instance variable from Container to InteractiveViewer).
Then yes I can use pinch zoom but no the paint method is invoked all the time, which is what I wanted to avoid.