# how to use shouldRepaint properly in flutter CustomPaint

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Now I have a canvas of CustomPaint which draws a sketch, the sketch illustrates a basic 2D movement of "fluids" in pipe. The pipe is generated only once, but the fluid movement is controlled by user input.

I have a result that needs optimization. I used one CustomPaint class to draw both in one canvas, and it redraws everything each time the user changes input.
What I need is optimization, i.e. to draw the pipe part which does not change and only repaint the fluids each time the user changes input. That would be better for resources as things get more complex.

I don't know how to use shouldRepaint or whether it's gonna be useful.
Would it be possible to draw on two layers, keep one static and the other "updateable".

```
class PipeProfile extends CustomPainter {
 FluidsData pipeData;
 WellProfileData fluidsData;

 PipeProfile({
 @required this.pipeData Data,
 @required this.fluidsData});

 @override
 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   cutomFunctionToDrawPipe(pipeData);
   cutomFunctionToDrawFluids(fluidsData);

 @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: check `Canvas.drawPicture`

Comment: but actually why dont you use `RepaintBoundary`? for example by using that [createLayers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406157/2252830) function?

Comment: can you illustrate with a simple example .. I never used it before so your example would be extremely helpful .. thanks

Comment: what you never used? `RepaintBoundary`?

Comment: canvas in flutter .. never tried customPaint or Repaint