# In Flutter, how to associate device pixel ratio with a canvas created from scratch?

Tags: image, flutter, canvas, fuzzy

I'm using the following code snippet to record and get an image from a canvas. The image shows fuzzy on some devices.

```
setLayerBuffer(int layerID) async {
 recorder = new ui.PictureRecorder();
 canvas2 = new Canvas(recorder, canvasRect); //canvasRect is the drawing area

 for (var myLayer in layers)
    if (myLayer.id == layerID) {
      if (myLayer.buffer != null) {
        canvas2.drawImage(myLayer.buffer, new Offset(0.0, 0.0), Paint());
      }
      doPaint(canvas2, 1); //this will draw on canvas2
      break;
    }

 var picture = recorder.endRecording();
 buffer = await picture.toImage(
    canvasRect!.width.round(), canvasRect!.height.round());
 setBuffer(layerID, buffer!);  // store image as buffer in layer
 paintController.myNotifyListeners(); //paint the main canvas wiht buffers of layers
```

}

According to this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17782, the canvas created from scratch is not being set with device pixel ratio unlike the canvas created by CustomPaint.

I did try to set canvas scale with device pixel ratio as suggested by the above link. However, the    image disappears after setting the scale. How do I set the canvas to use the device pixel ratio ?

Comment: @pskink I'm trying to build a drawing app with multiple layers. I have modified the question with original code from my app.  I use canvas2 to draw all the buffers from layers and also new drawings, then use the image captured to draw on main canvas of a CustomPaint.  It works fine except the image shows fuzzy on some devices. I can try to create another CustomPaint canvas instead of using ui.PictureRecorder but I have not figured our how to pass back the second CustomPaint canvas back to the main drawing class.

Comment: tried to work with `Picture`s (drawn with `Canvas.drawPicture` method) instead of `Image`s?

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the tip. I'll give a try. It may not make any difference since the issue is with the canvas that is used by PictureRecorder.  The canvas created in this way doesn't know the dpr. I did try with isAntiAlias and  filterQuality for Paint parameters but they don't help much.

Comment: images are like raster graphics, pictures ar like vector one - you can scale the canvas before calling `drawPicture` and the output will not be rasterized like in images

Comment: @pskink you are correct. Instead of using image, I changed it to drawPicture. The fuzzy looking is gone. However, the performance is very bad. After a few draws, the app is no longer responded.

Comment: Canvas.drawPicture is really a performance issue. It quickly consumes a lot memory and trigger GCs. It freezes the app.

Comment: well, so you have to work with raster images :-(

Comment: btw you could also take a look at `RepaintBoundary` that can be useful with your layers - i dont know your exact use case but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406157/2252830) could help - notice that every `CustomPainter` passed to `createLayers` function draws only once

Comment: @pskink thanks. I use `RepaintBoundary` to save off the image. I'm exploring a second `CustomPaint` with no widget attached to it but using `Globalkey` so that I can use `RepaintBoundary` to obtain the image.  It would be much easier with `ui.PictureRecorder` if the creating canvas works.