Flutter Maps drawing Polylines: Performance question
I am using the flutter_map to show a map in my flutter App:
FlutterMap(
  mapController: widget.mapController,
  children: [
    SvgPolylineLayer(polylines: polylines),
  ],
)

The SvgPolylineLayer is basically a clone of the already existing class PolylineLayer from flutter_map. I can't use that class because I want to customize my lines in a way that is not possible with PolylineLayer. So I created my own widget that is pretty much a clone, but comes with my own customizations (which are not included in the example here, because it is not necessary)
class SvgPolylineLayer extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<SvgPolyline> polylines;
  final bool polylineCulling;

  const SvgPolylineLayer({
    super.key,
    this.polylines = const [],
    this.pointerDistanceTolerance = 15,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final map = MapCamera.of(context);

    return MobileLayerTransformer(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(
          map.size.x,
          map.size.y,
        ),
        isComplex: true,
        painter: SvgPolylinePainter(
          widget.polylineCulling
              ? allPolylines
                  .where(
                      (p) => p.boundingBox.isOverlapping(map.visibleBounds))
                  .toList()
              : allPolylines,
          map,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SvgPolylinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<SvgPolyline> polylines;

  final MapCamera map;
  final LatLngBounds bounds;

  SvgPolylinePainter(this.polylines, this.map) : bounds = map.visibleBounds;

  Offset getOffset(LatLng point) => map.getOffsetFromOrigin(point);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (final polyline in polylines) {
      // This is just a method that calculates the points on the map
      final offsets = getOffsets(polyline.points);
      if (offsets.isEmpty) {
        continue;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < offsets.length - 1; i++) {
        final p1 = offsets[i];
        final p2 = offsets[i + 1];

        // Draw path between the two points
        drawPath(p1, p2);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant SvgPolylinePainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.bounds != bounds ||
        oldDelegate.polylines.length != polylines.length ||
        oldDelegate.hash != hash;
  }
}

As you can see, the painter goes through each polyline, and through each line within the polyline and draws every line individually. This is necessary, because every line will have a different paint.
Now, it is possible that I have several hundred polylines on my map. With each polyline having a lot of individual lines, that means I have to draw a lot of paths. I want to animate some lines, which means that I have to update the SvgPolylineLayer many times. Everytime I want to change the appearance of one polyline, I have to draw the whole Widget again.
So my question now is the following:
I also thought about creating a Widget like the one above, but instead of passing the whole List of Polylines, I just pass one polyline. And the widget draws only that one polyline. Then, I would need a Widget for every poliline and pass all those widgets to the children parameter in the FlutterMap widget. This way, when I animate a polyline, only that one polyline gets drawn again and again, and all the other polylines don't (because for them, shouldRepaint returns false). But I would have a Stack of maybe a hundred Widgets. I wanted to ask what is the better way. The way I currently built it, or the way I just described here.

check RepaintBoundary widget - one of my answers here shows how to use it for multiple layers and with an option to update a single layer in a group - I would need to find it...

I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400716/how-to-set-z-index-of-canvas-elements#64406157

Thanks. Is that still a good solution if I have 100 or more polylines? That would mean 100 painters.

hmmm, are they always visible? or in practice only few are visible and the rest (lets say 90 or more) are off screen?

Not all the lines are visible, but there are over 100 visible ones sometimes

Seems to work fine. Thank you!
